# LocalNotification limit

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I know Apple puts a limit of the number of local notifications at 64. After reading Apple's docs, some posts on SO and blogs... I am a bit confused.

Is it:

1. You can only schedule 64 total notifications for the app ever.
2. You cannot have more than 64 notifications scheduled at one time.(do
   they delete automatically after the fireDate?

Answer (score 4):

Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications (not notifications from server).

Notifications will reset when you open the app, thus you can send another 64 after every time you close the application.

> The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit,
>   keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest.
>   Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

Give a different "requestWithIdentifier" for each notification and try, may it works for you.

```
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"youridentifier" content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
UNUserNotificationCenter *userCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[userCenter addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
    }

}];
```

Comment: Where did you get the fact that notifications reset when you open the app? In reality this is not the case. Also, please include a reference for your quote. Your code is in Objective-C instead of Swift and doesn't solve the problem, a single app can only have 64scheduled notifications all together regardless of their identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when notification is firing its deleting automatically. So you can schedule another notifications. If you set more than 64 notifications the first one will be removed with the new one. So be careful.
I've solved this problem with scheduling only 60 notifications and when user entering in app - remove all notification and scheduling new 60 notification again in  `applicationWillTerminate`.
For my app it's approximately a week of notifications.
Also you can try to use background fetch to update your notifications. You can find more info about background fetch in 
[Ray Wenderlich tutorial for background modes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)